# I am trying to display a value from an AJAX call in html using flask

Tags: python, jquery, html, ajax, flask

Hi Guys I am relatively new to web development. Basically, I am creating an application in flask. What I am trying to do now is to test an AJAX function to see if it is working. The AJAX function reads radio inputs from html. I want to display the AJAX call in html just to see if my code is working.

Here is my html code (index.html):

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">

  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions1" id="option1" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" >Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions1" id="option2" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions1" id="option3" value="option3">
  <label class="form-check-label">Dunno</label>
</div>
```

Here is my AJAX function:

```
$(function(){
     $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
        var radioValue1 = 
 $("input[name=inlineRadioOptions1]:checked").val();

        $.ajax({
                url: '/process',
                data: {value1: radioValue1},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
            }      
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my code in python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

# App config.
DEBUG = True
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '7d441f277y7ttt8t88tb'

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/process', methods = ['POST'])
def process(): 
    v1 = request.form['value1']
    return jsonify({'v1': v1})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Now I want to display the value v1 in index.html using a div tag. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set the header in the responce as `text/json` so the success function will give you `response` as json object . thene you can read it like so :

```
response.v1
```

to change the html values you can call the element by id :

```
$('#id_v1').text(response.v1)
```

now you need a container whare you want to display the data so you can add this in your html:

```
<input id="id_v1"> or <div id="id_v1"></div>
```

Comment: Flask's `jsonify` sets header `Content-Type: application/json` so there is no need to set it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Insert `<div id="result"></div>` in your `index.html` and place there the result in success handler:

```
        $.ajax({
                url: '/process',
                data: {value1: radioValue1},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    $('#result').text(response.v1);
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
            }      
        });
```